# How to execute GUI via ssh -x

Tags: user-interface, ssh, osx-elcapitan

dear all!

I have Mac OS X El Capitan, and I want to use server machine with ssh -x (to use browser on remote machine). The remote host is running Ubuntu.

What software do I have to install on both machines?

(Sorry if that question is too trivial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install XQuartz (or equivalent) on El Capitan and then run ssh -X